# How to get the time crossing from amplitude of a signal by LabVIEW

Tags: labview, amplitude

I am a labview new starter.

Here is my problem,I am working on a data processing LabVIEW program,now I use Threshold Detector VI to get the signals which have crossing the threshold,and I have the indices of these signals.but the indices are related to the amplitude of the signals,what I want is the time crossings of these signals.

What can I do?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Get Waveform Time Array](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361K-01/lvwave/get_waveform_time_array/#parent) to get an array of timestamps, then use your threshold indices to select from the timestamp array.